# What's the latest version of build-helper-maven-plugin that requires JDK 1.6?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, build-helper-maven-plugin

The latest version of the Build Helper Maven plugin (**1.10** at the moment) requires Java **1.7**, which broke my build. [The plugin documentation page](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) only shows Java version requirement for the latest version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at Build Helper Maven Plugin versions, [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin)

- version **1.9.1** points to parent POM [`org.codehaus.mojo.mojo-parent`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/mojo-parent) version **33**, which still sets its Java target at **1.5** (via the property `mojo.java.target`).
- version **1.10** points to parent POM org.codehaus.mojo.mojo-parent version **38**, which sets its Java target at **1.7**

Hence, Build Helper Maven Plugin **1.9.1** is the latest version compatible with Java **6**. From that version on, Java **7** is the default target.

Comment: Bummer, you typed it up faster than I did. Was just finishing mine up.  :P

Comment: Then I wish I could share reputation points for this answer : )